# Ruby Constants and Nested Classes

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to understand what the following will produce. According to [IRHG](http://trybeee.me/ruby_hackers_guide/chapter01.html), this code will return A1.

> IRHG says: Constants are search for first outside the class. If not found
>   outside,  then searched inside the class.

But I've got the following message in Ruby 1.8.7

> uninitialized constant A3::B3::C3::Const (NameError)

Would you please help me to understand this correctly?

```
class A1
    Const = "A1"
end
class A2 < A1
end
class A3 < A2
    #Const = "A3"
    class B1
    end
    class B2 < B1
    end
    class B3 < B2
        class C1
        end
        class C2 < C1
        end
        class C3 < C2
            p Const
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: It doesn't say they're searched inside *other* classes like `A1`, which would totally defeat the purpose of namespaces. Try the fully-qualified name -- `::A1::Const`.

Comment: But according to IRHG, it will return A1, why it didn't return it when I run the code.

Comment: I think you are referring to the graphic shown in the section "Constants and Nested Classes". It's just wrong.

Answer (score 1):

In your case C3 class isn't inherit from A3 class. A3 class is only a namespace for C3.

```
A3::B3::C3.superclass
#=> A3::B3::C2
A3::B3::C3.superclass.superclass
#=> A3::B3::C1
A3::B3::C3.superclass.superclass.superclass
#=> Object
# or you can look A3::B3::C3.ancestors for full map
```

While

```
A3.superclass
#=> A2
A2.superclass
#=> A1
```

So when you puts one class inside of another you don't inherit but nest classes

Comment: But according to IRHG, it will return A1, why it didn't return it when I run the code.