# Navigating up Ruby Objects

Tags: ruby, oop

Navigating down inside ruby objects is pretty straight forward.  Given the following pseudo code, and using this paragraph as example input, the following calls makes sense and works:

```
forth_word = Par.sentence[0].word[3]
puts forth_word.text #"ruby"
puts forth_word.type #:noun
```

Pseudo code of classes that are contained within each other: (sort of nested but not in strict OOP sense)

```
class Paragraph 
  @page_number = #1 (default)
  @sentences = []
end

class Sentence
  @is_a_quote = #false (default)
  @words = []
end

class Word
  @text =# "ruby"
  @type =# :noun 

  def in_a_quote?
    #... return Sentence.@is_a_quote 
  end

  def on_page
    #... return Paragraph.Sentence.page
  end
end
```

The tricky part becomes when I try to navigating up Ruby object tree...aka ask about from information from inside Word that belongs to Sentence or Paragraph objects.  Any suggestion how I could code the last 2 methods:

```
puts forth_word.in_a_quote  #false
puts forth_word.on_page     #1
```

Comment: This type of data structure is not suitable for your requirement. Store the data in sql and use an ORM to retrieve data as you envision it.

Comment: Please change "sudo" to "pseudo". It's driving me crazy. Also, for `Sentence` and `Word` to be nested you'd need to define them `class Sentence < Paragraph` and `class Word < Sentence`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Omigod, you are a genius. I was banging my head against the wall trying to figure out what this has to do with superuser permissions... But you are wrong in your next remark: OP is nesting not by hierarchy (is-a), but by containment (has-a, in instance variables), and it is the correct thing to do: a `Word` is certainly not a type of `Sentence`, nor is a `Sentence` a kind of `Paragraph`.

Comment: @Amadan, ha!, and thanks for the correction. Now I'm going back to sleepzzzzzzz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each word can have a sentence variable that points to the Sentence it is in. Same for Sentence and Paragraph- and Paragraph and Page.

Comment: Thanks! This seems like straight forward solution (I don't know why i didn't think of it) my only objection is it doesn't seem to be very DRY.  For every class I create I've got remember to put a placeholder to the 'parent' class.  Maybe this is only possible solution for how OOP is designed but I thought there might be native method.  It seems similar to navigating a web page DOM tree or XML doc.  Not sure if those parsers use pointers as you describe or some other magic.

Comment: Ruby variables are passed by reference by default, so it is very likely a pointer (I don't know for sure though). I do believe my solution is DRY because there isn't repeated code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your classes aren't nested. They should be declared inside each other.

```
class Paragraph 
  @page_number = #1 (default)
  @sentences = []

    class Sentence
      @is_a_quote = #false (default)
      @words = []

        class Word
          @text =# "ruby"
          @type =# :noun 
        end
    end
end
```

But unlike in Java in Ruby you can't access variables of outer class from inner one. [Ruby Constants and Nested Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788584/ruby-constants-and-nested-classes)
And it's better to use modules than nested classes.

But if you still want to use same hierarchy as in your example be aware of accessing data that is outside your class.
For example, you'll get an error if you try to execute this piece of code

```
class Word
  @text =# "ruby"
  @type =# :noun 

  def in_a_quote?
    #... return Sentence.@is_a_quote 
  end
end

w = Word.new
w.is_a_quote?
```

This is very dangerous and contradicts to OOP principles.

Comment: I agree that 'nested' isn't the proper term but not sure how else to describe it.  Can you explain why this is dangerous and what principles it would violate?

Comment: It's dangerous because the method Word.is_a_quote relies on supposition then there are some object of Sentence class and it has a parameter @is_a_quote. But what this method return if we delete @is_a_quote from Sentence class or simply try to execute a piece of code that I wrote in my answer? The encapsulation is violated totally. If you want a method `is_a_quote? you have to declare it in the Sentence class at in the most logical place.